# Unit testing a void method

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I understand that you can unit test a void method by checking for its effects. However, looking at the loadConfigFile method in this code:

```
    internal XmlDocument configData;

    public ConfigFile()
    {
        configData = new XmlDocument();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load config file into memory
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filename">path and filename of config file</param>
    public void loadConfigFile(string filename) 
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
            throw new System.ArgumentException("You must specify a filename");

        try 
        {
            configData.Load(filename);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Config file could not be loaded",ex);
        }
    }
```

It loads a config file into a private field - which needs to be kept private so that developers do not modify the value directly. Instead the modification will be done through setConfigValue and getConfigValue methods (which I would assume need to be tested separately).

Given this, how would I test that the loadConfigFile actually worked? As I cant access the private configData field.

Comment: may be you can read one config value from the file, and if it returns the expected value, then the file is also loaded properly. OR you can expose the private variable as a readonly property

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where else in that class is `configData` used?

If, say, you have a method like

```
public string GetValue()
{
    return configData.GetsomeDataFromThis;
}
```

Then I suggest you have a test like so:

```
public void ReadValueFromLoadedConfigData()
{
    // Arrange.
    const string ExpectedValue = "Whatever";

    var sut = new ConfigFile();

    sut.loadConfigFile(@"C:\PathToTheConfigFile");

    // Act.
    string actual = sut.GetConfigValue();

    // Assert.
    Assert.AreEqual(ExpectedValue, actual);
}
```

In your tests, try to test only the public interactions, since going deep into the class, by having to read values of private fields, means your class isn't test friendly.

Comment: I would also suggest creating mock classes for any external calls. Your tests, especially if you plan on automating them, should never depend on anything that could change depending on where the test is run. I would mock away the XmlDocument class and implement an "ObjectFactory" class that implements the mock or actual class and allows overriding which one is being called so that you can define it in your tests.

Comment: So really, I dont need a test method to check that the file was loaded, since the test methods that uses getConfigValue implies the file was loaded?

Comment: For this scenario yes, you're spot on there.

Answer (score 4):

You could test that `getConfigValue` returned the values loaded from the file, basically.

Just because you test `setConfigValue`/`getConfigValue` in other tests doesn't mean that you can't use them in the test for `loadConfigFile`.

As an aside, I'd *strongly* urge you to follow .NET naming conventions, starting your method names with capital letters. (I'd also urge you to make your field private rather than internal...)

Comment: That means tests for `getConfigValue` and `loadConfigFile` will become almost same isn't it? For me it feels like we're testing two things in a same method(loadConfigFile sets the value and getConfigValue reads it properly). Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: No, it means that you can test both functions using a single unit test. Calling one function should lead to a given result when calling the other function. Also, you can test that without a prior call to one function, the other will return null, for instance.

Comment: So really, I dont need a test method to check that the file was loaded, since the test methods that uses getConfigValue implies the file was loaded?

Comment: @RoyDictus Isn't that against best practice recommendation that "One should test only one thing in a single test"? I'm asking this because I'm not an expert in tests.

Comment: In this case, `getConfigValue` and `loadConfigFile` are, for all practical purposes, so closely linked that it makes total sense to test them together. It's like when you would test a property -- you would set it, then get its value in a single test, wouldn't you?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why it's okay to use methods in your tests that are being tested in other tests? I've heard that this is a bad practice, in case the methods are faulty therefore making the test invalid. But I think if you test those methods well in the other tests, it should be fine to use them in your test.

Comment: @Dennis: Because they're operating on related data. Almost *everything* is the product of multiple interactions. How can you test any instance method without calling a constructor, for example? Basically this is a matter of being pragmatic instead of dogmatic, IMO. I find there's far too much dogma in testing, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

A unit test is basically a way to say "given this input, verify that this happened", it is not a substitute for verifying that your application is in a valid state.

In the example, the loadConfigFile method throws an exception if the precondition is not met, or the load operation failed. This will then be detected in the unit test, which will fail.

If any other validation is needed on the config beyond that no exception is thrown, that should be handled in the class itself.